# Get Max from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I write this script in SQL server And I want get the food name with the Max of order count From this Joined Table . I can get Max value correct but when I add FoodName is select It give me an error.

```
SELECT  S.FoodName, MAX(S.OrderCount) FROM 
(SELECT FoodName,
    SUM(Number) AS OrderCount   
FROM tblFactor
INNER JOIN tblDetail
    ON tblFactor.Factor_ID = tblDetail.Factor_ID 
WHERE FactorDate = '2020-10-30'
GROUP BY FoodName)S
```

Here is The Error Message

> Column 'S.FoodName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

also I know I can use order by and top to achieve the food Name and Max order number but I want use the way I use in this script . Thank you for your answers

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; though the outer query isn't going to change the results from the inner query. The `MAX` value of a single value is the single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `ORDER BY` and `TOP (1)` directly on the result of the `join` query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) f.FoodName, SUM(d.Number) AS OrderCount   
FROM tblFactor f
INNER JOIN tblDetail d ON f.Factor_ID = d.Factor_ID 
WHERE f.FactorDate = '2020-10-30'
GROUP BY f.FoodName
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
```

Notes:

- I added table aliases to the query, and prefixed each column with the table it (presumably !) comes from; you might need to review that, as I had to make assumptions
- If you want to allow top ties, use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` instead

Comment: I want to know is any way to dont use top and order by

Comment: @ArezooFarahi: why so? This seems like the simplest way to express your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have an aggregation function in the outer query `MAX()` and an unaggregated column.  Hence, the database expects a `GROUP BY`.

Instead, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT FoodName, SUM(Number) AS OrderCount   
FROM tblFactor f INNER JOIN
     tblDetail d
     ON fd.Factor_ID = d.Factor_ID 
WHERE FactorDate = '2020-10-30'
GROUP BY FoodName
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  In a query that references multiple tables, you should qualify all column references.  It is not clear where the columns come from, so I cannot do that for this query.